# can you explain trim and what is doing?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have this code

```
pvEnd INTEGER;
pvChk INTEGER;
pvDays INTEGER;
curCalendar P_CLUB_CALENDAR%ROWTYPE;
pvData VARCHAR2(30000):=pvWizard1;
pvAmenity VARCHAR2(5000);
vErr INTEGER:=0;
BEGIN
curPropRecord.OVERBOOK_MAX_PERCENT:=TRIM(Stringextract(pvData));
curPropRecord.INF_SRC_DB:=TRIM(Stringextract(pvData));
```

i dont know if this is the best question to ask, but what is

```
       curPropRecord.OVERBOOK_MAX_PERCENT:=TRIM(Stringextract(pvData));
```

doing?
what does it mean by `trim(stringextract(pvdata))`?

Comment: Did you check the Oracle documentation? `TRIM` is well documented, and a very quick Google search on 'trim function oracle plsql` returned a ton of useful results. It's important to do at least basic research yourself before posting a new question here. You've also posted a chunk of code out of context; there's no indication of what `pvWizard1` and `Stringextract` might be, but `pvData` is simply a `VARCHAR(30000)` column (string of multibyte characters).

Comment: yes i did, i couldnt find something that explain it well enough to understand

Comment: What part of "The Oracle TRIM function removes leading and trailing spaces from a string or column." (from the brief description of one of the search results) is not clear enough to understand? Your question is "Can you explain trim", which is pretty clearly explained in that sentence.

Comment: [Trimming (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_%28programming%29) in Wikipedia. Btw. `trim` is SQL function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple terms, `trim` removes whitespace from the beginning or end of a bit of text. For instance, it will turn `'myvalue '` into `'myvalue'` and `'   tonsofexteriorwhitespace   '` into `'tonsofexteriorwhitespace'`. Note that it won't remove whitespace from the *interior* of the text though, so `' interior spaces remain    '` becomes `'interior spaces remain'`.

It is often used to compare bits of whose actual content should be equal but may differ in leading or trailing spaces due to file loading/user input.